# Get UITapGestureRecognizer to recognize touches when they begin?

Tags: ios, uitableview, touchesbegan

Is there any way to get UITapGestureRecognizer to run on touch began?

I can't use touchesBegan because I am using a UITableView and the super view steals the event essentially.

I just want to detect when the screen is first touched. Why is this so difficult? Maybe I need a different solution than using tapgesturerecognizer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `state` property of `UIGestureRecognizer` to identify various states of any gesture -

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly) UIGestureRecognizerState state;  // the current state of the gesture recognizer
```

So when the gesture begin, use something like this in your registered handler method -

```
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It returns false 100% of the time for some reason, even though it's relative stateEnded works just fine..

Comment: This is because UITapGestureRecognizer is not a continuous recognizer. Recognizers for discrete gestures transition from UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible to UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed or UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized. This is different from continuous recognizers like pan or pinch, which transition through began, changed, ended. You could try to use the state possible, but be weary, as this doesn't necessarily mean the user has tapped, they could be starting a different gesture. I'd recommend using a UIControl, with a UIControlStateHighlighted state target action pair.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a tap gesture recognizer to the tableView in `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureRecognized:)];
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

Then implement this method:

```
- (void)tapGestureRecognized:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"tap gesture recognized");
}
```

Just tested this out, and works fine. For every tap i get the log message on my console. Note that this prevents the tableview from receiving the taps, other gestures will just be handled by the table view as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set delaysContentTouches = NO